# JQuery: Why HTML button is not getting enabled even using Prop and Attr?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is HTML code:

```
<table class="documents dataTable no-footer" data-enable-element=" button.delete,button.archive,button.chupa" id="DataTables_Table_0" role="grid">
```

Following JQuery code gets executed first on click of checkbox

```
if ($(this).attr("data-enable-element")) {
                var element = $(this).attr("data-enable-element");
                var checkboxes = $(this).find("tbody input[type=Type1]").filter(":not(input[name=Type2]) :not(input[name=Type3])");
                $(element).prop("disabled", checkboxes.filter(":checked").length == 0).toggle(checkboxes.length > 0);
                checkboxes.unbind("change").change(function () {
                    $(element).prop("disabled", checkboxes.filter(":checked").length == 0);
                });
            }
```

This disables button.delete

I have added more code to enable it; immediately after call of above code. The code added is below:

```
$("button.delete").prop('disabled', false);
```

But it is not enabling,

I also tried:

```
$("button.delete").attr('disabled', false);
```

But when I try

```
$("button.delete").hide();
```

then it successfully hides.

Could anyone get the reason why the button is not getting enabled? and how to fix?

Comment: provide a working snippet

Comment: have you tried removing attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue might be because of jquery version:

```
version < 1.7
$("button.delete").attr('disabled','disabled');

or

version >= 1.7  
$("button.delete").prop('disabled',true);
```

Comment: It is jquery-2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

A *button* is disabled if it contains `disabled` attribute

```
<button class="btnCss" text="Click Me" > Enabled Button</button>

<button class="btnCss" text="Click Me" disabled>Disabled Button</button>
```

try removing disbaled attribute like this (using jQUery) :

```
$("button.delete").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Refer jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) for usage details

OR like this using javascript :

```
document.getElementById("ButtonID").disabled = false;
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Well it is not easy to made as lots of JS and HTML :( I will try one.
or i will mix remove Attr and prop together

Comment: Do you think it is related to code which executed first? any issue with unbinding?

Comment: Can you try using javascript use this code : document.getElementById("yourButtonID").disabled = false;

Comment: There is no ID, let me try using classname

Comment: have you tried $('#btnRun').prop("disabled", false) as indicated in Uphar's answer below ?

Comment: Yes it did not worked. What i did i remove "button.delete" from "data-enable-element" and it is working fine; but i do not want it to work that way. The reason i was saying if any issue in method call describe in first script in question